# Component variable does not update when selecting option from select tag

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, axios

I want to populate a second select tag based on the selected option from the first select tag. When i choose from the first select tag, I get the correct response from the API but the variable that i declared in the component does not get updated. Every other variables get updated accordingly. When i use **vue-resource**, the variable gets updated only when i **make alternate choice** in the first select based on the previous chosen option. No success using axios. Below is the trimmed version of sample code:

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Bind</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control m-b" name="DataSource" v-on:change="FetchFields" V-model="BindTo">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a data source</option>
        <option v-for="Template in Templates" :value="Template.Id" :key="Template.Id">{{ Template.TName }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Data Source</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select class="form-control m-b" name="Field" v-model="FieldToBind">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a Field</option>
        <option v-for="Field in TemplateCustomFields" :value="Field.Id" :key="Field.Id">{{ Field.CName }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

VueJS Part

```
data: () => {
    return {
        TemplateCustomFields: [],
        CustomFieldTypeSelected: '',
        ShowAdditionalFieldChoice: false,
        Templates: [],
        BindTo: '',
        FieldToBind:'',
    };
},
methods:{
FetchFields() {
    console.log(this.BindTo);
    if (this.BindTo != "0") {
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:57802/api/gettemplatebyid',
            params: {
                Id: this.BindTo
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            this.TemplateCustomFields = response.data
        })
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scoping issue in your promise's `then` method. Callbacks in `JavaScript` create their own execution context, so `this` does not refer to the `Vue` instance. To solve this you can either, use an [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which does not create a new `this`:

```
FetchFields() {
  if (this.BindTo != "0") {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:57802/api/gettemplatebyid',
      params: {
        Id: this.BindTo
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.TemplateCustomFields = response.data
    })
  }
```

Or you can assign `this` to something:

```
FetchFields() {
  var self = this;
  if (this.BindTo != "0") {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:57802/api/gettemplatebyid',
      params: {
        Id: this.BindTo
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      self.TemplateCustomFields = response.data
    })
  }
```

Or you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
FetchFields() {
  if (this.BindTo != "0") {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:57802/api/gettemplatebyid',
      params: {
        Id: this.BindTo
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      this.TemplateCustomFields = response.data
    }.bind(this))
  }
```